# How to choose the order of distributions in KL divergence

Tags: distance, kullback-leibler, covariate-shift

While building ML model I'm facing a covariate shift detection, so I need to compare old labelled data and new unlabelled data. I'm planning to use KL divergence to quantify the distances between these two distributions. However, KL divergence is asymmetric. Hence, which distribution should be $P(x)$ and which $Q(x)$? My intuition is $P(x)$ should be new, unlabelled (inference) data and $Q(x)$ should be old, historic (training) data.

KL divergence is defined like this:
$$
\DeclareMathOperator {\KL}{KL}
\KL(P || Q) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(x) \log \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} \; dx
$$